# In Javascript, simple calculator, not working

Tags: javascript, function, prompt

I tried to get numbers by prompt(), and also action name. But the result is not as expected

i am new to programming..
code:

```js
function add(n1, n2){   return n1 + n2;}

function sub(n1, n2){   return n1 - n2;}

function mult(n1, n2){  return n1 * n2;}

function div(n1, n2){   return n1/n2;}


function calculator(n1, n2, action){

    alert(action(n1, n2));
}

calculator(prompt("first no,"), prompt("second No"), prompt("calc"));
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `action` has to be a function but you pass it a string (which the browser will tell you in the console: `TypeError: action is not a function`)

Comment: Rather than doing this, you can create an object having these methods and call the methods.

Comment: where should i change in this code to work as I expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take time to learn some basics, you can't convert a string to a function call unless you use eval() like this:

```
function add(n1, n2){ return n1 + n2;}
function sub(n1, n2){ return n1 - n2;}
function mult(n1, n2){ return n1 * n2;}
function div(n1, n2){ return n1/n2;}

function calculator(n1, n2, action){
alert(eval(`${action}(${n1}, ${n2})`));
}

calculator(prompt("first no,"), prompt("second No"), prompt("calc"));
```

But this is really hacky and unsafe code, a better approach would be:

```
const ops = {
"add": (n1, n2) => n1 + n2,
"sub": (n1, n2) => n1 - n2,
"mult": (n1, n2) => n1 * n2,
"div": (n1, n2) => n1/n2
}

function calculator(n1, n2, action){
alert(ops[action](parseFloat(n1), parseFloat(n2)));
}

calculator(prompt("first no,"), prompt("second No"), prompt("calc"));
```

Also notice the parseFloat(), if you keep the parameters as strings you will get:

`input: "1", "2", "add"` `output: "12"`

Answer (score 5):

Two things you need to do:

1. Parse the input as float
2. Map the function name given by the user

```js
function add(n1, n2) { return n1 + n2; }
function sub(n1, n2) { return n1 - n2; }
function mult(n1, n2) { return n1 * n2; }
function div(n1, n2) { return n1 / n2; }

function calculator(n1, n2, action) {
  alert(action(n1, n2));
}

function findOperation(name) {
  switch (name) {
    case "sub":
      return sub;
    case "mult":
      return mult;
    case "div":
      return div;
    case "add":
    default:
      return add;
  }
}

calculator(
  parseFloat(prompt("first no,")),
  parseFloat(prompt("second No")),
  findOperation(prompt("Operation Name?"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the calculator function should be :

```
function calculator(n1, n2, action){

    alert(eval(action+'('+n1+', '+n2+')'));
}
```